# Split line by line text file

Tags: php, html

I have this kind of text file.

```
"u901_humext    ""2019-02-01 23:24""    99.74   99.9    99.82".
```

And I want to read line one by one and put into a variable like:

```
name = u901_humext 
date = 2019-02-01 23:24 
min = 99.74
```

But I don't know how to split it.

Comment: Explode string by two space using `explode()`

Comment: Is that you syntax inside your text file? Do you think JSON would work with a random characters syntax? I think your first step would be to give a format to the data in your text file before we can give you any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below:

```
$string = '"u901_humext ""2019-02-01 23:24"" 99.74 99.9 99.82"';

$explodedArray = explode('"', $string);

foreach($explodedArray as $key => $element){
  $explodedArray[$key] = trim($element, ' "');
}
echo "Name: ".$explodedArray[0]."\n";
echo "Date: ".$explodedArray[1]."\n";
echo "Min: ".$explodedArray[2];
```

**Explanation:**

1. Firstly split the string using `explode()` function of PHP.
2. Then loop through each element of the array. Trim each element of the array to remove `"`(double quote) and (space).
3. Print the elements

Comment: its not working. i have this to read text file: < $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); but i have this error :< Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 10

Comment: are you getting any error? can you share more please?

Comment: Because @Imran wrapped string with `'`

Comment: In that case it will definitely not work. In the script I have written the $string should contain `string` not file. But seems you are passing the files here instead of the content of the file. use `<?php $myfile = get_file_contents('text.txt'); ?>` to get the content.

Comment: results : Name: Date: u901_humext Min:  it stil witout working